# How to display 'save image' at Activity View Controller (ActionSheetIOS.showActionSheetWithOptions)?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want to save an image via `ActivityViewController` at iOS simulator (iPhone X - 12.1).

I use `ActionSheetIOS.showShareActionSheetWithOptions` of react-native
APIs, but 'save image' doesn't appear at ActivityViewController.

[image]

`NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` and `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` are already set in `Info.plist`.

```
<View style={styles.isCenter}>
    <Button
        title="save"
        onPress={Platform.OS === 'ios'
            ? () => ActionSheetIOS.showShareActionSheetWithOptions(
                { url: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/header_logo.png' },
                () => {},
                () => console.tron.log('success.'),
            ) : () => {
                // abbreviation for android
            }
        }
    />
</View>
```

Comment: Maybe, showShareActionSheetWithOptions cannot deal with remote file.